# Install Go.CD external plugins

Tags: go-cd

I am trying to add a plugins to go-cd. Unfortunately this plugin does not appear in go administrations plugins tab. The go server is installed on a windows machine. This is the first external plugin I am installing, so I followed the instruction by putting the jars file in the plugins/external folder and then restarted the server.
Is there anything else to do?

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide more information? What is the version of GoCD server and what plugin (with version) are you trying to install?

Comment: Sure, Go version is 16.10
And the plugin is gocd-slack-build-notifier version v1.4.0-RC10 (https://github.com/ashwanthkumar/gocd-slack-build-notifier)
Thanks

Comment: Can you make sure that downloaded `jar` is not corrupted? You can use any archive manager (e.g. `7z` should work) and try to open it. That's just a guess... I'm trying to reproduce your problem in the Docker container.

Comment: So far so good... The plugin is installed and I can see that it's not configured: `Class [GoNotificationPlugin] is annotated with @Extension but cannot be constructed. Reason: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find go_notify.conf. Please make sure you've set it up right..`. After creating a file `go_notify.conf` looks like it's loaded fine.
Can you please check http://<your-go-server>/go/admin/plugins for suspicious messages from plugin?

Comment: The jar is not corrupted.
I just checked from the plugins tab and gocd is not there.
I'll try downloading other version of gocd and other plugins, to see if the issue persist. I'll post the result here.
Thanks for your help @grundic

Comment: I tried to add others plugins and it's not working. I'll have to look into that later, this not a priority. But I'll update this questions when this is fixed.

Comment: @grundic in fact there was a message http://<your-go-server>/go/admin/plugins that said "Plugin with ID (yum) is not valid: Incompatible with current operating system 'Windows' ". I totally ignored this message cause I thought it was for another plugin and just thought it was not relevant to my case.
So sorry for the bother and thanks for the help.
I'll see if we can upgrade to new version that support that.